# Custom API endpoint and Javascript tracking code

Tags: javascript, api, django-rest-framework

How does one create a tracking script using Javascript that calls an API endpoint securely?

For example let's say I have a web app that captures users details via an API end point. This is hosted on its own.

I want to be able to 'copy and paste' a Javascipt script and paste it on another site so it can start capturing users details once a form is filled in.

I understand how to make this happen. What I don't understand is how does one make this secure?

If I create a 'copy and paste' script all the sensitive token details will be exposed in the source etc. Then someone could easily attack my API endpoint.

How do sites do this? For example Google Analytic's has copy paste tracking code. Whats stopping someone attacking someone else's Javascript script? HubSpot they have tracking code. etc.
How do they do this?